# How can I calculate the coordinates of the two extremes of a line when it is rotated?

Tags: trigonometry

I've been trying to make a computer-generated line that can be rotated, but I clearly lack basic trigonometric understanding:

Have two points creating a line. One is $(-100,200)$ and the other is $(100,200)$.

Clearly the line is a straight one, with a length of $200$.

Suppose that I want to rotate this line $45$ degrees, with the pivot point being $(0,200)$. How can I compute the new coordinates for the two points?

Answer (score 0):

The rotating matrix for angle $\theta$ is $R_\theta=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\cos\left(\theta\right) & \sin\left(\theta\right)\\
-\sin\left(\theta\right) & \cos\left(\theta\right)
\end{array}\right)$. This rotation is around the origin, so if you want to rotate around another point $p$, then first move $p$ to the origin, then rotate, and then return the origin to $p$. Formally, a vector $v$ is moved to $p+A_\theta (v-p)$. You should try to apply these two operators on some points to see that you understand what they do (for example, check that for $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$ you actually get a $\frac{\pi}{2}$ rotation.

Another way to do this, is to think of everything as complex numbers instead of two dimensional real vectors. Then the rotation is just multiplication by $e^{i\theta}$, and in your case, since you want 45 degrees, it is just multiplication by $\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}$ (after the translation by the point $p=0+200i$ that I mentioned above).